# javascript confirm function return false

Tags: javascript, confirm

I want to show a message which writing are you sure … 
I can show the message but user click NO `return false;` did not work

```
<script>
function askCar(){
  var answer = confirm ("Are you sure for deleting car ?");
  if (answer){

  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

I call function with onclick here

```
echo '<td><a onclick="askCar()" href="arac-sil.php?sid='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico del">Sil</a><a href="arac-duzenle.php?did='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico edit">Düzenle</a></td>';
```

Comment: You know you can do negative conditionals? eg. `if (!answer) return false`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the return value:

```
<a onclick="return askCar();" ... >
```

Just having it inside the `onclick` will execute the function but to actually cancel the click, you need to use the return value.

Also, the code can be slightly optimized:

```
function askCar(){
    return confirm ("Are you sure for deleting car ?");
}
```

No need in `if..else` when you can directly return the dialog result. (unless of course you want to perform exra actions)

Comment: you answer absolutely correct, but in some cases with many scripts on page (or with with bad scripts compatible) it works just with block: else{
    return false;
  }

Comment: @Alex not sure what you mean. When using `return`, there is no point in any if..then - unless I miss something. Feel free to elaborate in chat, you should see "start a new room" button [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `return` also:

```
echo '<td>
    <a onclick="return askCar()" href="arac-sil.php?sid='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico del">Sil</a>
    <a href="arac-duzenle.php?did='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico edit">Düzenle</a>
    </td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onclick` function needs to use the `return` value:

```
echo '<td>
         <a onclick="return askCar()" href="arac-sil.php?sid='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico del">
            Sil
         </a>
         <a href="arac-duzenle.php?did='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico edit">
             Düzenle
         </a>
      </td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return` within your function definition, you must have to use `return` in the place where you are calling that. Otherwise, you will not get proper result. So, the best code would be below

```
echo '<td><a onclick="return askCar()" href="arac-sil.php?sid='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico del">Sil</a><a href="arac-duzenle.php?did='.$data["Car_ID"].'" class="ico edit">Düzenle</a></td>';
```